# equivalent of set() function in fortran?

Tags: fortran, set

Is there an equivalent of [`set()` function of python](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/set) in fortran or should I use a loop?

To do the equivalent of

```
Aux=set(Graph[Start])-set(path)
```

Currently using this:

```
X1=Start(1)
Y1=Start(2)
Z1=Start(3)
i=0
DO Xv=1,Ximax    
    DO Yv=1,Yimax
        DO Zv=1,Zimax     
            IF (MatrixCom(X1,Y1,Z1,Xv,Yv,Zv)==1) THEN
                DO Nv=1,Nmax
                    IF(Xv/=Path(1, Nv) .AND. Yv/=Path(2, Nv) .AND. Zv/=Path(3, Nv))THEN
                         i=i+1
                         AuxP(1, i)=Xv
                         AuxP(2, i)=Yv
                         AuxP(3, i)=Zv              
                     END IF
                 END DO
             END IF
         END DO
     END DO
 END DO
```

Is there a shorter way?

Comment: Perhaps if you explained what `set` does someone who lacks Python knowledge would be able to assist. That aside, yes you should (almost certainly) use a loop.

Comment: I edit my post with a link, to be more clear I want the value which are in an array `A1` that not are in an array `A2`

Comment: I don't think if there is function or concept equivalent to sets in Python. Although I believe that is a strength of Fortran, otherwise would not likely need to migrate from Python to Fortran. Two other suggestions:
1. The way your array MatrixCom is indexed is highly inefficient. Keep in mind that the rightmost index of the array should correspond to the outermost loop. That is not the case with your code above.
2. you can summarize your three-line array assignment in inner most loop as the following:
AuxP(:,i) = reshape( [xv,yv,zv], shape=shape(AuxP(:,i) ) )